# how to define a buffer of unknown size

Tags: algorithm, assembly, nasm

Got a task (in Assembly Intel, #Linux ELF32, NASM): read from a file of well known structure, it has a header which is not fixed in size. I'd like to open a file, read a header (till some well known stopbyte), then analyze it. Don't know how to define a BUFFER of unknown size... 
or I just shouldn't bother and read in fixed buffer till I get that stopbyte, then do the rest? or open a file twice? on 2nd attempt I'll know the size for sure. what's an elegant way of doing that task? 
thank you!

Comment: Same as in any other language - dynamic memory allocation. Call `malloc` or `mmap`.

Comment: If you are allowed to call the _C_ library then you could call `malloc` or `mmap`. You can also use the `sys_brk` system call directly.

Comment: good point but C libraries are not allowed (as yet). doing things as low level as possible. will dig into malloc/mmap direction. thank you!

Comment: @AlexTchaikovski `mmap` is a system call, so you can call it directly.

Comment: You may also use the stack: On an x86 system you read the file byte by byte, store the file in *reverse* order and every 100 bytes (for example) you perform a `sub $100, %esp`. On CPUs where the stack pointer is increased when pushing (such as TMS320F28) you can even store the file in correct order.

Comment: Do you have more specifics on the file format? The people who build these formats understand the need for easy readability. Without more specifics, it's rather difficult for us to provide a useful answer.